# ¿Cómo soluciono "sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 22: orden `s' sin terminar"?

Tags: bash, script, terminal, sed

Mi script tienen la siguiente linea:

```
#!/bin/bash
custom=$1
argsed="s/'manolo', /'manolo','"$custom"', /g";
gulpfile="/home/ricardo/mifolder/gulpfile.js"
sed -i $argsed $gulpfile
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me da:

`` sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 22: orden `s' sin terminar ``

Lo que quiero es agregar nombres a una lista.
tengo un js que contiene :

```
carpetas: ["manolo","Tere"];
y quiero agregar un nombre  a la lista cada vez.
```

Se que el problema esta en los espacios que hay tras las comas.
¿Cómo debo manejar ese carácter especial?

ya he probado a poner una barra antes del espacio: "\ " y sigue dando error.

pd:¿y si quiero poner un salto de linea?

Comment: ¿cómo lo ejecutas?

Comment: ./custom.sh argumento argumento

Comment: faltan datos. ¿Cómo rellenas el valor de `$custom`? ¿Qué quieres hacer realmente?

Comment: Ok, era por no añadir "ruido" porque creo que el problema esta en el espacio de las cadenas que quiero reemplazar en el sed.

Comment: sí, en este caso era necesario. La clave está en que le das a sed una expresión con comillas de más. En mi respuesta propongo una solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente usa las dobles comillas para la expresión Sed en general, y así la variable ya se expandirá:

```
sed "s/'manolo', /'manolo', '$nuevo_nombre', /" fichero.js
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
$ nuevo_nombre="kabezabolo"
$ cat fichero.js
carpetas: ['manolo', 'tere']
$ sed "s/'manolo', /'manolo', '$nuevo_nombre', /" fichero.js
carpetas: ['manolo', 'kabezabolo', 'tere']
```

En cualquier caso, procesar un fichero JSON con Sed es bastante frágil. Creo más útil usar una herramienta tipo `jq`:

```
$ nuevo_nombre="kabezabolo"
$ jq -r --arg var "$nuevo_nombre" '.carpetas += [$var]' fichero.js
{
  "carpetas": [
    "manolo",
    "tere",
    "kabezabolo"
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

El caso simple es:

```
$ cat fichero.js
{
    "carpetas": ["manolo", "tere"],
    "foo": "bar"
}
$ jq '.carpetas += ["hola"]' fichero.js
{
  "carpetas": [
    "manolo",
    "tere",
    "hola"
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: ok, pero me gustaría saber por qué falla si meto la expresión previamente en una variable.
Sobre el fichero: El fichero no es un json.

Comment: la clave aquí está en que estás cerrando la expresión antes de tiempo, seguramente por algún carácter que hay dentro de la variable que le pasas